# Starting & Stopping a Brightcove Video from Sitecore programmatically in a Fancybox Overlay

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, sitecore, fancybox-2, brightcove

So I have an issue with starting/stopping a Brightcove video that is coming from the Brightcove Video Connector with Sitecore 6.5.

Essentially, the built in  video connector provides with a "go and render the video in a Rich text Editor" and then wait until output time to get the iFrame with Brightcove JS content, et al.

To avoid the autostart from happening (as I want the autostart to occur after the video populates a Fancybox2 overlay), I am stuffing the HTML of the Rich Text Box into an input hidden value.  This makes me feel dirty all over, but it does work.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SitecoreSublayout.ascx.cs" Inherits="Assembly.SitecoreSublayout" %>
<%--CONTENT REMOVED--%>

<div class="wrapper black">
    <div class="page-header">       
            <div class="mobile-video-container">
                <customControl:Image Item="<%# DataOrContextItem %>" Field="VideoPlayLink" RemoveWidthHeight="true" runat="server" />
            </div>
                    <%--CONTENT REMOVED--%>

                    <div class="mobile-content"><sc:FieldRenderer ID="FieldRenderer1" FieldName="FieldName" runat="server" /></div>
                <a class="arrow-link expand-link" href="#">Expand For Full Story</a>
            </div>
            <%--CONTENT REMOVED--%>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="video-dialog">
    <input id="hdnVideoContent" type="hidden" value='<%# DataOrContextItem.Fields["VideoFieldName"] %>' />
</div>
```

When I call the JQuery event to open the Fancybox, I stuff the hidden's value into the content of the Fancybox2.  Since this includes an autoplay, it plays just fine.  In most browsers, this is working.  Unfortunately, I am supporting IE8, Android 4.1, iOS 7, et al.  They are not handling this transition to stop the video very well when the Fancybox closes.

```
GlobalObject.brightcoveOverlay = function () {
    $(".mobile-video-container, .video-container").on('click', function () {
        $.fancybox({
            'hideOnContentClick': false,
            'autoScale': false,
            'transitionIn': 'fade',
            'transitionOut': 'fade',
            content: $('#hdnVideoContent').val()
        }); // fancybox
        return false;
    }); // click
}();
```

Unfortunately, I cannot post the video code.  We under a client license and we have some NDAs preventing me from disclosing more than this functionality.

Anybody know of a good way to find the a Brightcove video by selector, hijack, and stop the video from playing before the Fancybox2 closes?  I inject my own Brightcove APIs, but I don't seem to have access via the normal Brightcove.API route.

Any and all suggestions are appreciated.  Just trying to mitigate things so I can solve some of the issues at hand.

Comment: Does the video stop if you just use [jQuery empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) to effectively delete the brightcove html from the Fancybox2 container when you handle the close?

Comment: It seems to work in some, but not all targeted browsers.

Comment: I am pursuing this path further, but feel like there are possibly other issues in the process that I need to resolve.